# Trying to install File::Find from CPAN

Tags: perl, cpan

Sorry about my original post.
My misunderstanding on a couple of fronts, so i'll clarify what I
wanted and where I stand corrected.

Was trying to get File::Find::Rule.

Went the Files::Find page on CPAN and hit download

1) Thinking that any package under Find::File would be
downloaded. I.e. File::Find::*, including Rule.

I now know that the Rule package resides in the File::Find namespace?
(if that word applies here), but has to be gotten individually.

2) Clicking on download, I got was perl.5.26 which was confusing to me.
So now I know that File::Find is packaged with Perl, hence I got the
entire Perl package. I.e. a core package.

I know better now

Comment: Looks like File::Find::Rule is another package to be installed separately. It doesn't come bundled with File::Find. See http://search.cpan.org/~rclamp/File-Find-Rule-0.34/lib/File/Find/Rule.pm

Comment: Correct. I downloaded that manually and built and installed to my local dir. There are further dependency issues with that.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use [File::Find::Rule](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File::Find::Rule), you'll need to install File::Find::Rule (`cpan File::Find::Rule`), not File::Find.

If you want to download File::Find::Rule's distribution, you'll need to download [File-Find-Rule](http://search.cpan.org/dist/File-Find-Rule/). It makes no sense to download File::Find's distribution if you want File::Find::Rule, especially considering File::Find is distributed as part of [perl](http://search.cpan.org/dist/perl).

If you want to use [File::Find](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File::Find), don't tell `perl` to load File::Find::Rule.

Comment: I'd like to use File::Find's routines. File::Find::Rule's interface looks interesting and wanted to give Rule a shot as well. I guess i'm missing something here, but why is File::Find perl itself ?? isnt File::Find just another perl lib/module ?? When i clicked on "download", i expected to download just the File::Find module

Comment: @technog: File::Find is a CORE module which comes bundled together with perl. That's why it also reports as already installed. To cite your own question: *"...it says its up to date !!!"*

Comment: Got it. Thanks! However a followup. Havent used cpan shell before. Does it do dependency checks? I downloaded Rule and got the an error: Can't locate Number/Compare.pm". Will download any further missing modules manually

Comment: What is `Find:::Rule`? That looks like a bug to me.

Comment: @shawnhcorey, Fixed